# MySQL: Stored procedure to insert data in many-to-many data model

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I need to store data (entries and tags) with many-to-many relationship in MySQL. Should it matter, I am using a server with MySQL 5.7.

With the many-to-many relationship in mind, I created three tables: entries, tags, entries_tags.

Table for entries (entries):

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `data2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data3` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data4` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table for tags (tags):

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table to store map entries-tags (entries_tags):

```
CREATE TABLE `entries_tags` (
  `eID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eID`,`tID`),
  KEY `fk_tags_idx` (`tID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entries` FOREIGN KEY (`eID`) REFERENCES `entries` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tags` FOREIGN KEY (`tID`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have also created a simple stored procedure to insert an entry in the entries table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=user@localhost PROCEDURE insert_entry(
        IN  _date          DATE, 
        IN  _data1        DOUBLE, 
        IN  _data2        VARCHAR(150),
        IN  _data3        VARCHAR(150), 
        IN  _data4        VARCHAR(150)
     )
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO entries
         (
           date,
           data1,
           data2,
           data3,
           data4,
         )
    VALUES 
         ( 
           _date,
           _data1,
           _data2,
           _data3,
           _data4,
         );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My goal is to have a stored procedure to insert the data in all three tables automatically. I want pass the following to the stored procedure:

- date [datetime]
- data1 [double]
- data2 [varchar(150)]
- data3 [varchar(150)]
- data4 [varchar(150)]
- tag_names [array of n strings]

After receiving the input, the stored procedure needs to:

- insert a new row in the entries table using insert_entry
- get the newly created entry id eID using [SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html)
- iterate over tag_names and get the corresponding tID from the tags table
- insert the n rows (eID, tID) in entries_tags

If a particular tag_name does not exist in the tags table yet, it should be added in a new row.

I have little experience programming in MySQL and would appreciate your guidance/criticism regarding the approach I outlined above.

Do you think there is a better/easier way to do this? If yes, what is it? Please provide a simple code example.

Thanks!

Comment: a stored procedure is overkill. Do it inside your program.

Comment: I am a big fan of "do it all in a stored proc (with a transaction)." Others have a different viewpoint. Such as "stored programs are evil", "the server cannot be trusted"  etc

Comment: @e4c5, The problem I see with doing it inside the program is that SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() does not seem to have any feature to guard against multiple users making requests on the client side at the same time. How would I get the entry id (generated with AUTOINCREMENT) back to the program in an efficient manner?

Comment: @dd_rlwll that is not a problem. It is connection based and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is thus protected. Otherwise this is what all implementations would do: [picture](http://www.reddirtreport.com/sites/default/files/articles/2016/02/images/Train-Wreck-1.jpg)

Comment: Easiest to do that is to code that into your program

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the remark, I did not know that LAST_INSERT_ID() was connection-based. Any chance you can post your answer using a stored procedure with a transaction?

Comment: How about if you do a self-answer and we work off that. And have a sample call at the bottom of it. A work-in-progress. To make it stellar, and some point in the future, add to it in the programming language of your choice. For 50k inserts (1 meaning all the tables) show performance with PlanA (what e4c5 said), versus PlanB (what I am babbling about). Your peers would probably like to see that.

Comment: yes @drew's suggestion is a good one. What's at the moment not a very good question might become a vote magnet for you